# App made with the Angular CLI hosted in IIS does not refresh automatically

Tags: angular, iis, teamcity, angular-cli, webdeploy

We have an app made with the Angular CLI v1.0.1, that we are deploying through TeamCity by using Web Deploy via a command line build step to put the output files onto the remote server.

Our output files is the dist folder when you `ng build`  in the apps root folder.

On a successful build we get our files successfully on the remote server, in the correct folder that is used by the site on IIS.

When we hit the URL (of the server) in our browser, the bundled javascript and css files are not loaded. Looking at the Chrome network tab on dev tools shows that all the correct files (main.bundles.js, vendor.bundles.js etc) have time "pending", and are not loaded.

However, when I remote on to the server and browse the website through the IIS panel, the website loads successfully, and then anytime after that, when you hit the website through the URL it loads successfully. This has happened each build so far.

I though it might be a caching issue at first but we've disabled cache through chrome dev tools, tried incognito, restarting the browser etc and none of these seem to work.

This also happens when we `ng build --prod`  as well.

Comment: u should use `ng build --prod --base-href .`